# Fingerprint sensor not working at all

Tags: 20.04, usb, security, thinkpad, lsusb

My fingerprint sensor does not work at all, it works on Windows though.

My device is a Thinkpad X1 Tablet G2. Running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. When running `lsusb` in terminal I get the following output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 17ef:60a3 Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Tablet Thin Keyboard Gen 2
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1199:9079 Sierra Wireless, Inc. Sierra Wireless EM7455 Qualcomm Snapdragon X7 LTE-A
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As far as I can see, there is no fingerprint sensor listed here. (There is also not option for fingerprint in the `Users` tab in Settings.)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you will need additional software to access the fingerprint scanner. An example that works on my Dell Laptop is Howdy, which works like Windows Hello.

To install Howdy, you need to add the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:boltgolt/howdy
sudo apt update
sudo apt install howdy
```

Comment: This is a facial authentication system? Does it provide the driver for the fingerprint scanner?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi seems to be right, on GitHub it says it is a facial authentication system. That wont help me much.